# How can I divide a month DTO into two parts as if it were a separate month?

Tags: java

**Task:**
I need to add up the work hours of the employees and display them in the Excel sheet for each month.

**Problem:**
For a given month, I need to add up and display the worked hours for the first 15 days and for the last 15 days. My months are stored in the DTO and my total hours are stored in a map. Each time I save my total hours in the same map for the same month. Result: I overwrite my first calculation.

**Question:** How can I divide a month into two parts as if it were a separate month?
The algorithm should recognise it as a separate month because many calculations depend on it.

*This is what it looked like*

|  | January | February | March | April | May |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Work hours | 150 | 140 | 120 | 130 | 160 |

*At the moment it looks like this*

|  | January | February | Day 1-15/ March | Day 16-30/ March | April | May |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Work hours | 150 | 140 | 70 | 70 | 130 | 160 |

*Result should look like this:*

|  | January | February | Day 1-15/ March | Day 16-30/ March | April | May |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Work hours | 150 | 140 | 70 | 50 | 130 | 160 |

**My code:**

```
public class CalcHoursExample {

private Map<YearMonth, BigDecimal> hoursOfMonths;

// Other codes...

private void calcHoursOfMonth(List<YearMonthDto> yearMonthDtos) {
        YearMonth start = YearMonth.of(yearMonthDtos.get(0).getYear(), yearMonthDtos.get(0).getMonth());

        YearMonth end = YearMonth.of(yearMonthDtos.get(yearMonthDtos.size() -1).getYear(),
                yearMonthDtos.get(yearMonthDtos.size() -1).getMonth());

        YearMonth previousMonth = YearMonth.of(2018, 4).minusMonths(1);

        Map<YearMonth, BigDecimal> result = new HashMap<>();

        int monthsLength;
        LocalDate firstDayOfMonth;
        BigDecimal hours;

        while (start.isBefore(end) || start.equals(end)) {
            hours = BigDecimal.ZERO;

            firstDayOfMonth = LocalDate.of(start.getYear(), start.getMonthValue(), 1);

            monthLength = start.lengthOfMonth();

            if (start.equals(previousMonth)) {
                hours = calcHoursForPartOfTheMonth(monthLength, firstDayOfMonth, true);
                result.put(start, hours);

                hours = calcHoursForPartOfTheMonth(monthLength, firstDayOfMonth, false);
                result.put(start, hours);

            } else {
                for (int i = 1; i <= monthLength; i++) {
                    hours = hours.add(getDayHours(firstDayOfMonth.withDayOfMonth(i)));
                    result.put(start, hours);
                }
            }

            // continue to next month
            start = start.plusMonths(1);

            hoursOfMonths= result;
        }
    }

    private BigDecimal calcHoursForPartOfTheMonth(int monthLength, LocalDate day,
                                                             boolean firstPartOfMonth) {
        BigDecimal hours = BigDecimal.ZERO;

        for (int i = 1; i <= monthLength; i++) {
            if (i > 15 && !firstPartOfMonth) {
                hours = hours.add(getDayHours(day.withDayOfMonth(i)));

            } else if (i <= 15 && firstPartOfMonth) {
                hours = hours.add(getHours ofDay(day.withDayOfMonth(i)));
            }
        }

        return hours;
    }
}
```

Comment: "The algorithm should recognise it as a separate month because many calculations depend on it." - I wouldn't represent this as a month as this will cause confusion and other problems down the road. Instead, I'd refactor the code to work with a certain period that's defined to have a start and end date and which can be mapped to a month, half a month, a week, a weekend etc.

Comment: There is a `java.time.Period` you could use. Maybe only store those `Period`s, they are capable of representing half a month, or a full one or any range of `LocalDate`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on my comment, I'd use a class to represent a concrete period in time as defined by a start and end date. Unfortunately, `java.time.Period` just represents the duration of such a period so you'd need to roll something yourself. Maybe call the class `ReportingPeriod` or something similar.

It could then look like this (simplified):

```
class ReportingPeriod {
  private final LocalDate start;
  private final LocalDate end;

  public ReportingPeriod(LocalDate s, LocalDate e) {
    start = s;
    end = e;
  }

  public ReportingPeriod(YearMonth month) {
    s = month.atDay(1);
    e = month.atEndOfMonth();
  }

  public boolean contains(LocalDate d) {
   return !(start.isAfter(d) || end.isBefore(d));
  }

  //hashCode() and equals()
}
```

and create a `Report` class

```
class Report {
  private final ReportingPeriod period;
  private Integer hours;

  //constructor, getters, setters
}
```

Assuming your periods are not allowed to overlap, use a treemap to store them in sorted order:

```
TreeMap<LocalDate, Report > report = new TreeMap<>();

//build the map as necessary, using the report's ReportPeriod's start day

while( ... ) { //loop over days
  
  Entry<LocalDate, Report> entry = report.floorEntry(day);

  Report report;

  if( entry == null ) {
     //handle this situation, there seems to be an entry missing at the start
  } else {
     report = entry.getValue();
  }

  if( report.getPeriod().contains(day) ) {
    //add hours
  } else {
    //there seems to be a gap since the latest period that starts at or before the day doesn't contain it
    //you might need to add a new report here, throw an exception or just ignore the hours
  }
}
```